# add_image_size() using ratio instead of sizes - WordPress

Tags: wordpress, image, wordpress-theming, addition, image-size

I'm developing a WordPress theme, and I need images that are uploaded via the inbuilt Media Uploader, to be the same ratio. I know this is easily done by defining the height and width and using crop.

Problem is that I want to use these images for a fullscreen slider, so having all images down to 300x200 as an example wouldn't work. I want to keep as much as the default size of the image as possible while cropping it for the ratio.

WordPress comes with a add_image_size() feature, but I'm more like looking for a add_image_ratio() feature. Is this even possible?

Comment: Have you thought about using the ThumbGen plugin?

Comment: I'm not much for using plugins for the theme. I'd rather have it all built right into the theme.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a ratio:

```php
$thubmnail_ratio = (150 / 200); // height to width ratio, you can use some existing working ratio

add_image_size( 'thumbnail-small',  100, round(100*$thubmnail_ratio), true );
add_image_size( 'thumbnail-medium', 200, round(200*$thubmnail_ratio), true );
add_image_size( 'thumbnail-large',  400, round(400*$thubmnail_ratio), true );
```

It should also be possible writing a little helper function that wraps add_image_size(...).